# dart contradicting itself about a JSON entity

Tags: flutter, dart, swagger-codegen

We used `swagger-codegen` to create a Dart API library from our .Net Core API. If you look at this picture from vscode:

[image]

(sorry for the ugly redaction) - in the exception message `List<dynamic>` is *not* what is in the JSON in the hover data, which is clearly a `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`.

The `listFromJson()` method is defined as:

```dart
static List<stampInfo> listFromJson(List<Map<String, dynamic>> json) {...}
```

The types in the relevant functions are correct. If this was an isolated exception I could hack my way around it but it is pervasive and gamebreaking with the `listFromJson()` entries.

Is there something in dart I can do to fix this at the application level? vscode seems to be showing the JSON correctly although Dart does not seem to agree with it. Any suggestions? Am I missing something?

Edit: This is actually a flutter app.
Edit: Added swagger-codegen tag.

Comment: Could you try `List<Map<String, dynamic>> json = new List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(json['topStamps'])`

Comment: @mertcamb your solution works fine, and I was fiddling with casting as well. It would take me several days to propagate that modification throughout the swagger API, I'm not sure if it's worth it. Thanks, though - that _does_ work....

Comment: I had to scrub a large number of errors out of the API generated by `swagger-codegen` before it would even build, mainly because the generator seems to be stuck on dart 1.x - I wonder if this is related to that.

Comment: Does sound like a possibility, but I'm not experienced with swagger. You can add it as a tag, maybe?

Comment: Actually the solution above does _not_ work in all cases, even though the json entries are the same format...